# Monotonic functions and zeros

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $I$ be an interval. Let $f: I\to \mathbb R$ be a function and $f '(x)$ is never zero, is it true that the function has at most one real zero?

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$? If not, you could have a function like $f(x) = |x| - 1$, with two zeros and no point with $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: We are assuming f is differentiable on an arbitrary interval of real numbers, I

Comment: Hint: use Rolle's Theorem, and prove the contrapositive.